# How to Break Loop in Parallel Block - Designer 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, loop

I have a List called **Test1** and below are the controls (only for testing purposes).

[image]

Below is my Designer 2013 workflow associated with the list above:

[image]

**The workflow does the following:**

- When a user submits a new item, the workflow Updates the **DueDate** to
  equal to a **Calculated column** called **CalcDueDate**. The calculated
  column is formulated to display the date as **Created + 14days** shown
  below:

[image]

- It then sets a variable
- I am using a Parallel Block because I have multiple scenarios that
  will move the workflow to the next step depending on what the user
  has selected. This parallel block will stop if loopVar returns True
  (Yes) in **Parallel Block Advanced Settings**.
- Next, in **Email Loop** Step, as long as **loopVar = No**, then the loop will pause for 1 minute
  and email Created By. This will continuously loop and email every
  minute.
- On the **Step Change Color To Red**, a user can *break out* of the Parallel
  Block if **Colors = Red**. This immediately stops the looping with
  continuous email every minute as expected.

The Step **Break Loop** is my focus. The desired effect is that when a user changes the DueDate to something other than what is already set by the Update activity, then it will exit the Parallel Block and move to the next Step.

In other words, if the DueDate has been changed then break the Loop and go to the next Step.

### The issue:

When the DueDate has been changed, the workflow continuous the Pause activity and Emails the Created By one more time before finally breaking out of the Loop.

### The desired:

When the DueDate has been changed then immediately stop the Loop and move to the next step.

However, I can’t come up with the logic that can do this and one that would actually work for that matter. I have been testing numerous possibilities but the same issue persists.

Any assistance would be helpful.

Comment: I have a situation similar to this example. I have a Approve/Reject parallel block step up in 2 steps. I assigned the Boolean workflow variable to find the answer that is "true". My problem is that the process doesn't continue after the parallel block and won't transition to any other actions, steps or stages. How did you get yours to continue?

Comment: What did you exactly do to achieve this as I am having the same issue, can you please share?

Answer (score -2):

Your question is vague!

But here is my two cent, based on my understanding what you need is some way to have a task with moving due date.

In parallel block try a task with due date set as CalcDueDate in one block and other blocks as usual.

Comment: Your answer is vague! I was able to figure it out.

Comment: please put it an answer for others benefit. thanks